# Does jQuery use proper DOM manipulation with append and creation of elements?

Tags: jquery, dom

So I just came across this problem:
[image]

Now the thing to note here is the fact that the dimensions are printed out using identical code:

```
$graphContainer.append("<br/>dimensions: ");
var width = $graphContainer[0].offsetWidth, height = $graphContainer[0].offsetHeight;       
$graphContainer.append(width + 'x' + height);
```

And the red DIV it the `$graphContainer` it self. The functions are called like this:

```
        s.load();
        setTimeout(function() {
            s.load()
        }, 350);
```

`s` being the  the object I am building. (If I used 300ms, then both came out as 800x30, so its between 300-350ms).

Now the DOM order is all correct and the elements were appended into the DOM using jQuery prior of this function being called. (A bit complicated logic, hopefully you can take my word, without having to see the hole code).

I think I actually know what is going own here, if you use innerHTML to append content, then it takes awhile for it to be fully available in the DOM, with can cause phantom stuff like this to happen. Now the timeline I am talking about is in the milliseconds, but for me that's bad enough to have a policy to never use innerHTML to append or make elements.

The thing is that all of the DOM elements used in the objects and the DOM manipulation done has been done using jQuery code like `$('<div>')` for creating elements and `$container.append($child)` for appending children.

I was always under the impression that jQuery did proper DOM manipulation.
Is that not true and they are using innerHTML extensively?
Or am I missing something and this could be something else the 300ms delay is a bit to long for it to be the innerHTML issue?

I am currently using jQuery 1.9.1

Just in case this is the code that get's this result (it's a jQuery plug-in):

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'function') {
    throw "The CommoditiesPeersIndices is a jQuery plugin i.e. jQuery needs to be defined first";
}

(function ($) {
    /*
        Built with jQuery 1.9.1 in mind.
        Creates the [CommoditiesPeersIndices] Object
    */


var CommoditiesPeersIndices = function(Settings) {
/*
    Binds all of the tools objects into a single object and manages them
*/
    var 
        CLASS_NAME = 'CommoditiesPeersIndices' //the CSS root Class name that will be applied to all the objects
    ;

    this.$root = $('<div>'); //the root of the object

    var This = this
        ,DefaultSettings = {
            //$container : null //the jQuery object into with the tool will be built
            parentClassName : '' //the parent class name name of the parent object that will be appended to this object
        }
    ;

    var s; //temp variale for the test small graph

    function _init() {
        //makes sure that the Settings object has all of the settings
        mergeSettings(Settings, DefaultSettings);
        CLASS_NAME = Settings.parentClassName + CLASS_NAME;

        s = new SmallGraphObject({
            parentClassName : CLASS_NAME + '-'
        });
        This.$root.append(s.$root);
    }

    this.load = function() {


        s.load();
        setTimeout(function() {
            s.load()
        }, 350);


    };

    function mergeSettings(targetObject, sourceObj) {
    /*
        Used to merge the DefaultSettings with the Settings object. Basically the targetObject will get all of the sourceObjects values that are missing from the target object or are not of the same type as the sourceObject value.
    */
        var name, targetType;
        if(typeof targetObject == 'object' && targetObject  != null) {
            //merges the user Settings object with the Default SettingsObject i.e. DefaultSettings
            for(name in sourceObj) {
                targetType = typeof targetObject[name];
                switch(targetType) {
                    case 'object':
                        if(targetType == null) {
                            targetObject[name] = Utility.copyObject(sourceObj[name]);
                        } else {
                            mergeSettings(targetObject[name], sourceObj[name])
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        if(typeof sourceObj[name] != typeof targetObject[name]) {
                            targetObject[name] = sourceObj[name];
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            targetObject = Utility.copyObject(sourceObj);
        }
    }   

    _init();
};var SmallGraphObject = function(Settings) {
/*
    The single small graph object on the page, holds the graph + the enlarge button
*/
    var 
        CLASS_NAME = 'SmallGraph'
    ;

    this.$root = $('<div>'); 

    var This = this
        ,DefaultSettings = {
            instrumentID : 1031004 //the instrument ID of the instrument who's data will be displayed.
            ,parentClassName : '' //the parent class name name of the parent object that will be appended to this object
            ,startDate : new Date()
            ,decimalPlaces : 2 //the number of decimal places the series will show
        }
        ,$graphContainer = $('<div>') //the highchart's container
        ,$header = $('<div>') //the header that holds the name and the enlarge button

        ,$container = $('<div>') //the container object of the [SmallGraph] to with you can place CSS
    ;

    function _init() {
        //makes sure that the Settings object has all of the settings
        mergeSettings(Settings, DefaultSettings);

        CLASS_NAME = Settings.parentClassName + CLASS_NAME;

        $container.addClass(CLASS_NAME + 'Container')
            .append($header.addClass(CLASS_NAME + '-Header'))
            .append($graphContainer.addClass(CLASS_NAME + '-Graph'))
        ;
        This.$root.addClass(CLASS_NAME).append($container);

        $header.text('Heading');
    }

    this.load = function() {
    /*
        Loads the series data from the server.
    */

        $graphContainer.append("<br/>dimensions: ");
        var width = $graphContainer[0].offsetWidth, height = $graphContainer[0].offsetHeight;       
        $graphContainer.append(width + 'x' + height);
    };

    function mergeSettings(targetObject, sourceObj) {
    /*
        Used to merge the DefaultSettings with the Settings object. Basically the targetObject will get all of the sourceObjects values that are missing from the target object or are not of the same type as the sourceObject value.
    */
        var name, targetType;
        if(typeof targetObject == 'object' && targetObject  != null) {
            //merges the user Settings object with the Default SettingsObject i.e. DefaultSettings
            for(name in sourceObj) {
                targetType = typeof targetObject[name];
                switch(targetType) {
                    case 'object':
                        if(targetType == null) {
                            targetObject[name] = Utility.copyObject(sourceObj[name]);
                        } else {
                            mergeSettings(targetObject[name], sourceObj[name])
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        if(typeof sourceObj[name] != typeof targetObject[name]) {
                            targetObject[name] = sourceObj[name];
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            targetObject = Utility.copyObject(sourceObj);
        }
    }

    _init();
};

    $.fn.CommoditiesPeersIndices = function() {
    /*
        Creates a new instance of [CommoditiesPeersIndices]
    */    
        var Main = new CommoditiesPeersIndices({
                parentClassName : 'Tools-'
            })
            ,$head = $('head')    
        ;

        $head.append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:60226/Content/jQueryComponent.css" />');
        $head.append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:60226/Config/Company/test/test.css" />');

        this.append(Main.$root);
        Main.load();

        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

With this CSS:

```
.Tools-CommoditiesPeersIndices-SmallGraph {
    width: 300px;

}
.Tools-CommoditiesPeersIndices-SmallGraph-Graph {
    height: 150px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to: "What's in the jQuery source code?" In which case, [you could always just see for yourself](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/).

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? That you are creating two identical elements but they end up having different dimensions? Yes, jQuery uses `innerHTML` where it makes sense.

Comment: You don't seem to be waiting for the stylesheets to be done loading (toward the bottom of the code snippet for anyone looking for it), that could be affecting the dimensions.

Comment: @KevinB I feel like a noob :) thank you! this was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some explanation about the mechanics of jQuery on the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). This is what the docs say about passing in a node as a parameter, e.g. `$('<div>')`:

> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as
>   it is in the above example, the actual creation of the elements is
>   handled by the browser's innerHTML mechanism. In most cases, jQuery
>   creates a new  element and sets the innerHTML property of the
>   element to the HTML snippet that was passed in. When the parameter has
>   a single tag (with optional closing tag or quick-closing) — $( "" ) or $( "" ), $( "" ) or $( "" ) — jQuery creates
>   the element using the native JavaScript createElement() function.

So, if you are throwing in more than just a single tag, innerHTML kicks in:

```
var foo = $("<div>");                   // this will use createElement
var bar = $("<div><p>hello</p></div>"); // innerHTML will be used here
var doh = $("<div class='hello'>");     // also innerHTML here...
```

I also had issues with the creation of elements by jQuery being too slow (specifically on Internet Explorer), so I went ahead and made use of the native functions `createElement` and `createTextNode`, my god it was suddenly fast as hell!

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js it differes based on which method is used to create the element and, like you said, how complex the element is. (buildFragment is what is used when you do `$("sometextorhtml")`)